# Spring Webflux: Handle error when one Mono is empty in a Mono.zip

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

My code is as below

```
public Mono<Ship> getShip() { 
    //... 
}

public Mono<Car> getCar() { 
    //... 
}

public Mono<ShipAndCar> getCombinedMono() {
    Mono<Ship> shipMono = getShip();
    Mono<Car> carMono = getCar();

    return Mono.zip(shipMono, carMono
                    (ship, car) -> return new ShipAndCar(ship, car);

}
```

As both `getShip` and `getCar` can return error or empty Mono. I'd like to return something like `Mono.error(new Exception("Custom message"))` where the message depends on which Mono is empty. How do I do that?

If I add a `switchIfEmpty` after the Mono.zip, I wouldn't know which component Mono is empty...

Answer (score 1):

You can supply default arguments in the case of an empty Producer:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

public class JavaTest {

     @Test
     public void nullCarProducesSpecificException() {
        Mono<Ship> shipMono = Mono.empty();
        Mono<Car> carMono = Mono.empty();

        var map = Mono.zip(
                shipMono.defaultIfEmpty(new Ship("US Default")),
                carMono.switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Car was missing!!"))))
            .map(tuple -> new ShipAndCar(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()));

        StepVerifier.create(map)
            .verifyErrorMatches(error ->
                error instanceof RuntimeException &&
                    "Car was missing!!".equals(error.getMessage())
            );

    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you zip them in your code you can extend each input mono with the switchIfEmpty operator like this

```java
        var carAndShip = Mono.zip(
                Optional.ofNullable(shipMono)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("ship is null"))
                        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("ship is empty"))),
                Optional.ofNullable(carMono)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("car is null"))
                        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("car is empty"))),
                ShipAndCar::new
        );
```

Comment: It will still throw `NullPointerException` when creating `ShipAndCar` and not RuntimeException :(

Comment: if the pass mono can be null then you can add a check with Optional. It looks a bit ugly tho.

Comment: The question is about shipMono or carMono being a Mono.empty() ,
Not about it being null